# What is the clear purpose of Globle temporary tables?

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I have referred documents for Global temporary tables, but not understand the clear purpose of the temporary table.

Here is the URL which I have referred: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/97fc7a/local-and-global-temporary-tables-in-sql-server-2008/

Could anyone help me to understand Global tables and the difference between Local and Global Temporary Tables? When would one use global temporary tables vs. local ones? Do they have a special purpose?

Comment: I think that article explains the differences between the two pretty well. What specific questions do you have?

Comment: @alroc: Thanks for the quick reply. I need to understand it deep with examples.

Comment: @JigneshM.Mehta The topic is widely covered and there are plenty of articles with in depth examples. You need to research more if you want to get deep understanding.

Comment: @JigneshM.Mehta "deep" understanding does not come from a Stack Overflow post, but rather from experience. What specifically do you need to "deep examples" of?

Comment: @dfundako: I just need to know the clear purpose of both tables, is especially the scope of both the tables in the real scenarios.

Comment: The scope is described very clearly in the article you linked.

Comment: @alroc: Yes, But not in the real scenarios. I appreciate the efforts of this post, but need to know when it will use, as like as we know local temp tables are created in the stored procedures, so when we use global tables? Any special purpose for the GLOBAL tables?

Comment: You should edit your question to be more specific so that your *actual questions* are addressed. As written, your question A) is answered by the link you posted and B) is far too broad compared to the question(s) that surfaced in the comments here.

Comment: @arloc: Thanks for the quickest reply. You deserve +1. I simply wrote that what is the clear purpose of the GLOBAL tables. If it does not address the actual question then could you please help me to depict actual question? if you can help, It will be a great delight to me.

Comment: @JigneshM.Mehta We're going in circles here. The questions you're asking in the comments here (especially the one before my previous answer) are much more specific and I suspect they're what you're really looking for.

Comment: @arloc: It looks pretty good and clear. Thanks a lot for help. appreciate your efforts. :)

Comment: Simply put, if you do not fully understand how global temp tables work then you should just avoid them. They are fraught with concurrency issues. In my 20+ years I have used exactly zero global temp tables for anything. The only time they are really useful is for administrative tasks and I prefer to use a persistent table for those kinds of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between temp tables and global temp tables is their scope. This is described in the article you linked; temp tables are only visible from the stored procedure or session that created them and destroyed when that scope terminates. Global temp tables are available from anywhere, and are destroyed when no sessions reference them any longer.

My most common usage of global temp tables is when working with dynamic SQL. Because dynamic SQL is executed in a different scope than the query where it's defined (via `sp_executesql`), it can't access a temp table in the calling SQL from within the dynamic SQL.

Instead, I declare a global temp table then access that from within the dynamic SQL. This is usually in the context of collecting data from a number of databases at once, using a cursor to loop through all the databases and inserting into the global temp table.

Comment: Very simple and clever answer. Thanks a lot. I need to sharpen my mind from this types of problems. Let me accept your answer. :) I really appreciate your help and knowledge.

Comment: Actually a temp table can be accessed from dynamic sql with no problem. If you define a temp table and then execute dynamic sql in the same session you absolutely can get to the temp table.

Answer (score 2):

A local temp table, with a single # during declaration, is visible to only the session/connection that made it. Global temp tables, with 2 ##'s, are visible to all sessions and connection.

You can see this in action if you open up SSMS, open up two query windows, make a table of each type, and try querying them both from each window.

Comment: I would also point out that the ## evaporates when the creating session ends.  +1

Comment: Thanks a lot. can you please tell me when it will use, as like as we know local temp tables are created in the stored procedures, so when we use global tables? Any special purpose for the GLOBAL tables?